# How to add interval between async line reads while using readline module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, readline

I can stream a file line-by-line in Node.js like this:

```
var rd = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'),
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
  console.log(line);
});
```

Is there a way to add an interval between each `console.log()` call while also making the whole process async?

**Meaning that any log statements produced from any other part of the program gets published on the console mixed in with the statements from the readline**

My server is listening for incoming messages that need to be published. When they are coming in, they do not get published until after `readline` has read the entire file.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Maybe there's an alternative way of doing it.

Comment: The gist of it is that I am producing two kinds of messages. One from a static log file and other from clients. For the file I just run through each line in the file using readline. But this file can be really big and so any incoming messages from client need to be published as and when they come too. I would like to pause the readline from file when a message from client comes in and then resume from the same spot when the client message is published. The pausing on an incoming message can be done but how do you tell that the message has been published on the console.

Comment: Sorry if I have convoluted things further :)

Comment: You want to throttle console log?

Comment: for the readline output, yes. but also have it non-blocking

Answer (score 0):

Every message is processed only in 1sec interval

```
// debounce function - await fn call with timeout
// credits: https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
rd.on('line', debounce(function(line) {
  console.log(line);
}, 1000)); // <== call fn only within 1sec
```

Pseudo output:

```
1sec:
  line: some text
  log: some text

2sec:
  line: another text
  log: another text

2.5sec:
  line: quick message text

2.9sec:
  line: dota 2 manila major   

3sec:
  log: quick message text
  log: dota 2 manila major
```